# Get Pseudo Selector Style of a node in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, phantomjs

I did a bit of research and found out a way to get the pseudo selector style in JavaScript. We can do it as show below.

```
cssRules = window.getMatchedCSSRules(node, 'first-line')
```

But when i use the same in phantomJS, then it returns the css rules of the node itself, ignoring the rule of the pseudo selector.

How can i get the css rules for the pseudo selector?

Example :

HTML CODE

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #fl::first-line{
            color : red;
        }
        #fl{
            color : yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = 'fl'>Convert this</div>
    <div id = 'data'></div>
</body>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var node = document.getElementById('data');
var target = document.getElementById('fl')
console.log(window.getMatchedCSSRules(target, 'first-line')[0].style.color);
```

On web browser i get output as red, but in phantomJS i get output as yellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be implemented in PhantomJS 1.9.7, but works as expected in PhantomJS 2.0.0:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

var url = 'http://example.com';

page.open(url, function(){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(page.evaluate(function(){
        document.head.innerHTML = "<style>body::first-line{color : red;}body{color : yellow;}</style>";
        return {
            parent: getMatchedCSSRules(document.querySelector("body")),
            pseudo: getMatchedCSSRules(document.querySelector("body"), "first-line")
        };
    }), undefined, 4));
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Output:

```json
{
    "parent": {
        "0": {
            "CHARSET_RULE": 2,
            "FONT_FACE_RULE": 5,
            "IMPORT_RULE": 3,
            "MEDIA_RULE": 4,
            "PAGE_RULE": 6,
            "STYLE_RULE": 1,
            "UNKNOWN_RULE": 0,
            "WEBKIT_KEYFRAMES_RULE": 7,
            "WEBKIT_KEYFRAME_RULE": 8,
            "WEBKIT_REGION_RULE": 16,
            "cssText": "body { color: yellow; }",
            "parentRule": "",
            "parentStyleSheet": "",
            "selectorText": "body",
            "style": {
                "0": "color",
                ...
                "clipRule": "",
                "color": "yellow",
                "colorInterpolation": "",
                "colorInterpolationFilters": "",
                "colorProfile": "",
                "colorRendering": "",
                "content": "",
                ...
                "zoom": ""
            },
            "type": 1
        },
        "item": {},
        "length": 1
    },
    "pseudo": {
        "0": {
            "CHARSET_RULE": 2,
            "FONT_FACE_RULE": 5,
            "IMPORT_RULE": 3,
            "MEDIA_RULE": 4,
            "PAGE_RULE": 6,
            "STYLE_RULE": 1,
            "UNKNOWN_RULE": 0,
            "WEBKIT_KEYFRAMES_RULE": 7,
            "WEBKIT_KEYFRAME_RULE": 8,
            "WEBKIT_REGION_RULE": 16,
            "cssText": "body::first-line { color: red; }",
            "parentRule": "",
            "parentStyleSheet": "",
            "selectorText": "body::first-line",
            "style": {
                "0": "color",
                ...
                "clipRule": "",
                "color": "red",
                "colorInterpolation": "",
                "colorInterpolationFilters": "",
                "colorProfile": "",
                "colorRendering": "",
                "content": "",
                "counterIncrement": "",
                "counterReset": "",
                "cssText": "color: red;",
                ...
                "zoom": ""
            },
            "type": 1
        },
        "item": null,
        "length": 1
    }
}
```

Note that PhantomJS doesn't return an array, but an object with integer keys, so you need to access it this way:

```
getMatchedCSSRules(el, "first-line")["0"].style.color
```

instead of

```
getMatchedCSSRules(el, "first-line")[0].style.color
```